# Random walk with $p+q<1$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation, random-walk, stopping-times

Consider a one-dimensional random walk with

$p_{i,i+1}=p$,

$p_{i+1,i}=q$,

$p_{i,i}=r$.

The expected time $k_i$ to hit the boundary $\{0,n\}$ starting at $i$ satisfies the recurrence equation

$k_i= 1 + p\, k_{i+1} + r\, k_i+q\, k_{i-1}$

and the boundary conditions $k_0=k_n=0$. If $p\neq q$ the solutions have the form

$\displaystyle k_i\ =\ \frac{i}{q-p}+A +B\bigg(\frac{q}{p}\bigg)^{\!i}$

where $A$ and $B$ are determined by the boundary conditions.

**Question** Is this correct? If correct, why does it not depend on $r$?

Comment: It sort of does depend on $r$, inasmuch as $r = 1 - q - p$, and it depends on $q$ and $p$. I haven't verified if it's correct, though.

Comment: (indeed, you can immediately subtract $rk_i$ from your recurrence to get $(p + q)k_i = 1 + pk_{i+1} + qk_{i-1}$)

Comment: Thank you. You are right! (I am sorry, it was not a clever question.)